# Boost log linking errors (Cmake Mingw32)

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mingw, mingw32

I have this cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

find_package(Boost 1.54.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS log)

add_executable(TestProject main.cpp)

target_include_directories(TestProject PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(TestProject Boost::log)
add_definitions("-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB") # Disable boost auto-linking.
add_definitions("-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK") # Avoid linking errors with boost::log
```

If I build it using Visual Studio as my generator from a Visual-Studio developer console, I can build just fine.  However in my MinGW32 environment I get linker errors.  I can confirm that boost is installed in my mingw32 environment and is working well for other projects (which use other boost components).

```
stewart@PC-1234 MINGW32 ~/src/testproj/buildmsys
$ tree /mingw32 -f | grep libboost_log
│   ├── /mingw32/bin/libboost_log_setup-mt.dll
│   ├── /mingw32/bin/libboost_log-mt.dll
│   ├── /mingw32/lib/libboost_log_setup-mt.a
│   ├── /mingw32/lib/libboost_log_setup-mt.dll.a
│   ├── /mingw32/lib/libboost_log-mt.a
│   ├── /mingw32/lib/libboost_log-mt.dll.a
```

I build with:

```
$ mkdir buildmsys && cd buildmsys
$ cmake .. -GNinja
$ cmake --build .
```

And here is the output

```
stewart@PC-1234 MINGW32 ~/src/TestProject/buildmsys
$ cmake .. -GNinja
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   log
--   date_time
--   log_setup
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   regex
--   chrono
--   atomic
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
C:/msys64/home/stewart/src/TestProject/buildmsys

stewart@PC-1234 MINGW32 ~/src/TestProject/buildmsys
$ cmake --build .
[1/1] Linking CXX executable TestProject.exe
FAILED: TestProject.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\mingw32\bin\c++.exe CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj  -o TestProject.exe -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_log-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_log_setup-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_system-mt.dll.a C:/msys64/mingw32/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.dll.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x151): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt64core3getEv'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x2b5): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt64core10set_filterERKNS1_6filterE'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x35a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt64core3getEv'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x4e2): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt64core10set_filterERKNS1_6filterE'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt67trivial6logger3getEv'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text+0x5a2): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt67trivial6logger3getEv'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt614attribute_nameC1EPKc[__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt614attribute_nameC1EPKc]+0x10): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt614attribute_name18get_id_from_stringEPKc'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt615value_extractorINS1_7trivial14severity_levelENS1_16fallback_to_noneENS3_3tag8severityEEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE[__ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt615value_extractorINS1_7trivial14severity_levelENS1_16fallback_to_noneENS3_3tag8severityEEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE]+0x19): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt619attribute_value_set4findENS1_14attribute_nameE'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt615value_extractorINS1_7trivial14severity_levelENS1_16fallback_to_noneENS3_3tag8severityEEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE[__ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt615value_extractorINS1_7trivial14severity_levelENS1_16fallback_to_noneENS3_3tag8severityEEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE]+0x2e): undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt619attribute_value_set3endEv'
CMakeFiles/TestProject.dir/main.cpp.obj:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt615value_extractorINS1_7trivial14severity_levelENS1_16fallback_to_noneENS3_3tag8severityEEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE[__ZNK5boost3log9v2_mt_nt615value_extractorINS1_7trivial14severity_levelENS1_16fallback_to_noneENS3_3tag8severityEEclERKNS1_14attribute_nameERKNS1_19attribute_value_setE]+0xe0): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt63aux26attach_attribute_name_infoERNS_9exceptionERKNS1_14attribute_nameE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What's wrong with my setup?

Note: I've already checked (and tried) these links in case my question was a duplicate:

- [Mingw32 Boost Log Link Errors: InterlockedCompareExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205353/mingw32-boost-log-link-errors-interlockedcompareexchange) (migration issue)
- [boost log link error 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330532/boost-log-link-error-2019)  (BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK issue)
- [Boost-log linker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688744/boost-log-linker-error)  (Unicode issue)
- [link error with boost log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24906597/link-error-with-boost-log) (Unicode issue)
- [Visual Studio 2013 Boost-log v1_61_0 linking errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931669/visual-studio-2013-boost-log-v1-61-0-linking-errors) (boost installation issue)

If I look at those solutions, the unicode one is the only one I haven't gotten to work.  I've added `add_definitions("-Zc:wchar_t")` to my Cmake file, but I get an unrecognized command line option error from c++.exe (since that flag is VS-specific).

Comment: `I can confirm that boost is installed in my mingw32 environment and is working well for other projects` - Can you get compile line for other project (which uses Boost) and **compare** it with the compile line generated by CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by mismatch of the target Windows version between your code and Boost.Log. See this answer:

[Problems Linking boost log 1_60 with MinGw on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34394896/problems-linking-boost-log-1-60-with-mingw-on-windows-7/34412436#34412436)

Most likely, your project defines `_WIN32_WINNT` somewhere to a value of `0x0600` or higher.

Boost defaults to Windows XP when compiled by MinGW because Windows SDK provided by MinGW is too incomplete.

Comment: That was the problem.  `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600` was indeed in the code.  How did you associate my problem with that cause?

Comment: You can see the version namespace in the missing symbols is `v2_mt_nt6`, which means your code is compiled for Vista or later. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html. The problems with MinGW Windows SDK I just know because I had those.

Comment: An experience thing!  I'm slowly getting more of that and I appreciate your help.